# read file using InputStreamReader?

Tags: java

Basically I have a web-app and I am trying to read youtube API  client_secrets.json using `InputStreamReader` and assign its value to `Reader`.

I tried:

```
Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(
            Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("/home/hazrat/Documents/eclipse-jee-neon-3-linux-gtk-x86_64/eclipse/client_secrets.json"));
```

FYI: This file is located in an external directory an not in my eclipse resources directory.

But the above code throws a nullpointerexception even though if I try my terminal `nano /home/hazrat/Documents/eclipse-jee-neon-3-linux-gtk-x86_64/eclipse/client_secrets.json` it opens the file in a text editor which basically Assures me that the file is in its location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to load a *file*, but you're using `Class.getResourceAsStream` to do so. If you want to load a file, use a `FileInputStream.` If you want to load a resource which is accessible to a `ClassLoader`, use `Class.getResourceAsStream` or `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`. They're different use cases, and should be handled with different code.

Note that the problem here has nothing to do with `Reader` or `InputStreamReader`. It's all about how you obtain the `InputStream` to start with. Having said that, I would encourage you to explicitly specify the encoding to use when creating an `InputStreamReader`, as otherwise you'll use the platform-default encoding.

Having said all of that, if you're on a modern version of Java, I'd use [`Files.newBufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-) to create a `Reader` for the specified `Path`, defaulting to UTF-8 (which is probably what you want).

Comment: Im sry to say this but can you tell me how to make a file accessible to a  classloader?

Comment: @IAintFixingIt: Well we don't know anything about your class. Is it in a jar file, for example? If it is, you'd probably need to bundle the JSON file in the jar file too. But if you're trying to access a file on the file system, it would be better to use `FileInputStream`.

Comment: @JOSkeet no its not in any jar file, classpath="/home/hazrat/workspace/RemoteSystemsTempFiles/Duck/src/duck/reg/pack/Auth.class"

Comment: Right, well copying the file under `/home/hazrat/workspace/RemoteSystemsTempFiles/Duc‌​k/src` would probably make it available. But again, `FileInputStream` would be a more natural solution, and you haven't given any explanation for why you don't want to use that.

Comment: @JoSkeet well I am trying to implement youtube api on my web-app and try to retrieve some youtube comments, and in its tutorial it appears that they r using "InputStreamReader" So I went with it

Comment: @IAintFixingIt: I never said not to use `InputStreamReader`. I explicitly said that the `InputStreamReader` *isn't* the problem. The problem is how you're getting the `InputStream` that you pass into the `InputStreamReader` constructor. You're calling `Class.getResourceAsStream`, and I'm saying to use a `FIleInputStream` instead of that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159562/discussion-between-iaintfixingit-and-jon-skeet).